# Somewhat Complex MySQL Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I am creating a forum, and have gotten stuck creating the page that will display all the topics for a given forum. The three relevant tables & fields are structured as follows:

```
Table: forums_topics    Table: forums_posts    Table: users
--------------------    -------------------    ------------
int id                  int id                 int id
int forum_id            int topic_id           varchar name
int creator             int poster
tinyint sticky          varchar subject
                        timestamp posted_on
```

I've started with the following SQL:

```
   SELECT t.id, 
          t.sticky, 
          u.name AS creator, 
          p.subject, 
          COUNT(p.id) AS posts,
          MAX(p.posted_on) AS last_post
     FROM forums_topics AS t
     JOIN users AS u
LEFT JOIN forums_posts AS p ON p.topic_id = t.id
    WHERE t.forum_id = 1 
      AND u.id = t.creator
 GROUP BY t.id
 ORDER BY t.sticky
```

This appears to be getting me what I want (topic's id number, if its a sticky, who made the topic, the subject of the topic, number of posts for each topic, and timestamp of latest post). If there is a mistake though please let me know.

What I am having trouble with now is how I can add to this to get the name of the lastest poster. Can someone explain how I would edit my SQL to do that? I can provide more details if needed, or restructure my tables if that will make it simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do this:

```
SELECT t.id, 
      t.sticky, 
      u.name AS creator, 
      p.subject, 
      COUNT(p.id) AS posts,
      MAX(p.posted_on) AS last_post,
      (SELECT name FROM users 
       JOIN forums_posts ON forums_posts.poster = users.id 
       WHERE forums_posts.id = MAX(p.id)) AS LastPoster
 FROM forums_topics AS t
 JOIN users AS u
LEFT JOIN forums_posts AS p ON p.topic_id = t.id
WHERE t.forum_id = 1 
  AND u.id = t.creator
GROUP BY t.id
ORDER BY t.sticky
```

Basically, you do a sub-query to find the user based upon the max id.  If your IDs are GUIDs or are not in order for some other reason, you could do the lookup based upon the posted_on timestamp instead.

Comment: That appears to do the trick, thank you very much! While poking around here I also found something interesting about joining the same table twice. This works so I'll use it and move on, but I'll make a note to come back and revisit this to see if maybe I can get it done without the subselect.